# Why does this Grails/HQL query with a JOIN return Lists of pairs of domain classes?

Tags: grails, join, hql

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a "join" in Groovy/Grails and the return values I get

```
person = User.get(user.id)
def latestPhotosForUser = PhotoOwner.findAll(
  "FROM PhotoOwner AS a, PhotoStorage AS b WHERE (a.owner=:person AND a.photo = b)", 
  [person:person], [max:3])
```

latestPhotosForUser isn't a list of PhotoOwners. It's a list of [PhotoOwner, PhotoStorage] pairs. Since I'm doing a PhotoOwner.findAll, I would have expected to see only PhotoOwners.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the proper behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`executeQuery` and `findAll` are a little misleading since the class that you call them on have no bearing on the query or its return type - GORM adds the methods to all domain classes.

Given the way you asked the question I'm assuming you want

```
def latestPhotosForUser = PhotoOwner.executeQuery(
   "SELECT b FROM PhotoOwner a, PhotoStorage b WHERE a.owner=:person AND a.photo = b",
   [person:person], [max:3])
```

Comment: Ok! I see. When you need to go to HQL, the dymanic function names like "findAll" have no real meaning and it's just an ExecuteQuery....

Comment: Essentially, yes.   I've never understood why there isn't a "Domain" static class that has these functions instead of placing them on all domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can achieve this by a dynamic finder, something like this:

```
def latestPhotosForUser = PhotoOwner.findAllByOwner(person, [max:3])
```

The you can just dig down into the latestPhotosForUser.photo in order to get to the storage.